# Canadian pension plan savings withdrawal upon leaving

Tags: canada, pension

I found a post on this forum that talked about Canadian pension funds being "withdrawable"

See answer here : 
[What happens to my saved Canadian pension funds when my SIN expires?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/34/what-happens-to-my-saved-canadian-pension-funds-when-my-sin-expires/5785#5785)

I've been in Canada for over 4 years now. Arrived in 2010 and have worked here with work visa until now (not got residence or applied for it) - so SIN is the temporary one

We've taken the decision to leave Canada for good this year. My question is if it is in fact possible to withdraw the pension deposits I've made in the time I worked here, how do I go about doing this? Who am I supposed to contact?

Comment: There is some relevant information [here](http://www.td.com/to-our-customers/tdhelps/#psce|cid=871|lid=1|tid=001|vid=b0d256631).

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Have you saved the money in an RRSP/SDRSP or through a company pension plan or CPP contributions or something else?